# How do I consecutively stack multiple tables one on top of another?

Tags: tables, floats

I have two (or more) tables. I would like to ensure that they are consecutively stacked right on top of one another vertically. I don't want them on separate pages. Do I need to put them into one figure?

Like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```latex
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{foo}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
10 & 11& 12 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{bar}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
13 & 14 & 15 \\ \hline
16 & 17 & 18 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{baz}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Just use a single `table` environment and populate it with `tabulat` environments and associated `\caption` directives.

Comment: If they all won't fit on one page, try using a  [p] table followed by  multiple [tp!} tables.